# Java heap space Exception and can't delete the file which recieved from server

Tags: java

I have written the code below, but after calling almost 150 times, it throws "Exception in thread "Thread-245" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" the problem just ocure in (b = new byte[1024 * 1024];)
Java Code:

```
class Client implements Runnable {
private Socket socket;
private BufferedInputStream bufin = null;
private BufferedOutputStream bufout = null;
String path;
private byte[] b;

Client(Socket socket, String path) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.path = path;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        bufin = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        bufout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));

        b = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        int num = 0;
        while ((num = bufin.read(b)) != -1)
            bufout .write(b, 0, num);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            bufin.close();
            bufout .close();
            b = null;
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I try to describe the problem more clearly. it is like this:
I write i ServerSocket, when a client send the request the Sever then put the request in a new thread as below:

```
public void start() {
      boolean started = false;
      try {
              ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
              started = true;
              while (started) {
              String path = "C:/Pic/"+ new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss_ms").format(new Date()) + ".jpg";
              Socket s = ss.accept();
              new Thread(new Client(s, path)).start();
             }
       } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

}

in this case the Server will recieve the request from any client...
and also the second problem which i think that problem will cause the Java heap space Exception, that is when the Server recieve the picture, then the picture can not be deleted from the disk before you close the server, when i delete it,
it says **"The action can't be completed because the file is open in Java(TM) platform SE Binary"**. Whereas i have already closed the input output in Client thread.
Now i can not discover the root of the problem, 1. why happen Heap Exception anr 2. why the file is not deletable from disk during server is running.
Thanks alot in advance of your reply!

Comment: You do not need b = null because it is done automatically as b gets out of the scope. Just declare b locally, where you allocate it and streams also. There is no need to declare all stuff in global scope. It is stupid and makes it difficult to review. Print the number of created/active/closed threads at the time of exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're running out of memory because each thread is creating a 1MB array buffer. You want to see what the max heap size is (this depends on a few variables) and increase your max size at the command line, example:
java -Xmx1024M myclass.class

Also, you said you started 150 clients. Why are they not getting garbage collected? Perhaps all 150 are starting instantly and all threads are grabbing for that memory at the same time? I recommend using a thread pool to execute these so you can put a limit on the running client count.

For your problem with the server holding the file (you can't delete it) is because you're getting that heap memory error. All bets are off when you get this. The server is still holding reference to the file and the bufout.close() probably did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the heap exhausted does not allow the program to operate properly after the exception occours and then in the finally block, leaving stream open. I suggest you change the program to allocate the memory block before opening the stream; in addition, to close the streams in the finally block I suggest you use the class IOUtils commons-io as described in the example:

[closeQuietly](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.OutputStream%29)

```
byte[] data = "Hello, World".getBytes();

OutputStream out = null;
try {
 out = new FileOutputStream("foo.txt");
 out.write(data);
 out.close(); //close errors are handled
} catch (IOException e) {
 // error handling
} finally {
 IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
}
```

This allows you to be sure that all streams are closed in the finally block.